# How to track the number of consumed requests whose resources are not in the main Azure AD storage?

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

The user has a number of properties that are not stored in Azure AD, such as

```
"aboutMe, birthday, hireDate, interests, mySite, pastProjects, preferredName, responsibilities, schools, skills"
```

They also cannot be obtained using the request
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview#properties-stored-outside-of-the-main-data-store

```
"GET /users"
```

They also cannot be obtained using the `/delta` request. If there are a lot of users in AAD, for example, more than 9,000, then to get these properties it will be necessary to make a request for each user to get these attributes.

```
_graphClient.Users[id].Request().Select("aboutMe, birthday, hireDate, interests, mySite, pastProjects, preferredName, responsibilities, schools, skills, id");
```

And this will lead to the second problem that I encountered code I get information about all these users in less than 10 minutes. This is the Retry-After response after about *9,000* requests.. The documentation says that there is an additional header `"x-ms-throttle-limit-percentage"` which notifies how many resources are left for these requests before the `"Retry-After"` will work, but I did not receive this header for this type of requests

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/throttling?view=graph-rest-1.0#regular-responses-requests

I have a question, the header `"x-ms-throttle-limit-percentage"` should come for properties that are outside of AAD, for example in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through service-specific limits as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling#service-specific-limits).

As general guidance please note that if no Retry-After header is provided by the response, we recommend implementing an exponential backoff retry policy. You can also implement more advanced patterns when building large-scale applications.

Microsoft Graph SDKs already implement handlers that rely on the Retry-After header or default to an exponential backoff retry policy.

Comment: I was not interested in getting Retry After, since this already imposes a limit and indicates that the request limit has been exhausted. I needed to get headers that contain information about the limit that I have left for this type of requests